# sharing a printer in windows 8 with a ubuntu machine on a network

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I'm struggling to share a printer that is connected to my windows 8 machine with a other ubuntu linux machines. It keeps on asking me the username and password to connect to the windows 8 machine. Even the same thing when browsing the network normally in home folder. I've tried all possible usernames and passwords, but no success. Please assist, I've checked all possible settings like sharing the printer and switching on printer file sharing support and also switched off passwords and still no success. I've also tried various ways and settings in gadmin samba in ubuntu and also no success. I don't know if I'm missing something or overlooking something. what else can I do? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Making printer visible on Windows PC by connecting it to Ubuntu one:

Connect the printer on Ubuntu PC (with static IP); Open web-browser on Windows PC and type `"IPadress of UbuntuPC":631`. Example: `192.168.1.15:631` CUPS control center will be opened. Go to `"Administration"` tab. Click `"Manage printers"` and right click on your printer name and Copy link. I don't know where it is on Win8, but find Add new printer(probably under Printers and faxes); add network printer and just paste that copied link of your ubuntu printer. Finish "add printer" wizard and it should work.

Comment: The printer in question on the windows 8 machine is a HP Laserjet 1200 printer.

Comment: Connect the printer on Ubuntu PC (with static IP);
Open web-browser on Windows PC and type "IPadress of UbuntuPC":631.

Example:  192.168.1.15:631

CUPS control center will be opened. Go to "Administration" tab. Click "Manage printers" and right click on your printer name and Copy link.

I don't know where it is on Win8, but find Add new printer(probably under Printers and faxes); add network printer and just paste that copied link of your ubuntu printer. Finish "add printer" wizard and it should work. :)